# Dark mode not applied to wifi network selection dialog box

Tags: 20.04

[This is the screenshot of what my wifi network dialog box looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifR77.png)
I have dark mode enabled globally. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 in my asus vivobook 15. Every where else dark mode works perfectlt fine.

Comment: Hi there! Maybe you could add some more information - e.g. if you are using a standard installation of Ubuntu (with gnome desktop), how you enabled the dark mode, and what theme are you using? This sounds like an issue with your theme.

Comment: Yup I'm using gnome. I have Yaru-dark theme. When I updated to 20.04 I was not able to switch to dark theme on settings (appearance). I read somewhere to install Yaru-dark theme and I was able to switch to ubuntu dark theme. Please help me solve this annoying issue. You may ask any other settings detail that may be relevant.
Thanks in advance!